# css 2 columns float text up to bottom of both, allow one column to extend into text

Tags: css, html, boilerplate

This should be ridiculously easy, but for the life of me I can't get this right. I have two columns, variable height. I have a div with text spanning the bottom of both columns. If the left column is the longest, I need the text div to go straight across and NOT float up into the right column:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Heading

blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah
```

However if the right col is the longest I need the text to flow into the space under the left col and then around the right column:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx
                xxxxxxxxx
Heading         xxxxxxxxx
                xxxxxxxxx
blah blah blah  xxxxxxxxx
blah blah blah  xxxxxxxxx
blah blah blah  xxxxxxxxx
blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah
```

I'm also trying to build the site as a responsive setup using mobile boilerplate and gridless.

What's the html/css? Someone put me out of my misery...

Comment: Marked Godinall's as correct - Anubhav yours also works but I don't really want to break the fluid/responsive thing by setting widths, and Godinall solution has only one width I need to think about. Thks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this looks like a case for publications, you only need to `float` the top right column and the rest is how you position your blocks.
Here's a [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Y8LhX/), you can adjust the content length of left bottom column to see it works as you described above.

Answer (score 1):

here is what you might be looking for:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8UF4P/)

html:

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="leftcol"></div>
        <div id="rightcol"></div>
        <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#leftcol, #rightcol {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
#content {
    clear:left;
    content:'';
}
#leftcol {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
}
#wrap {
    width: 405px;
}
#rightcol {
    height: 800px;
    float: right;
}
```

Just change the height of the right column from `800px` to `200px` and check your result.